# Can Gomory's cutting plane be used to solve Mixed Integer Linear Programs?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, simplex, branch-cuts

Do you know if Gomory's cut can be used to solve MILP problems ?

I have read that Gomory's cut is useful when all variables are integer, but what if just some of them are integer ?

Is is necessary to use a pure branch-and-bound algorithm or branch-and-cut or pure cutting plane can be used to speedup the process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are cuts that can be done in MILP problems.  Look up "GMI cut" (stands for Gomory Mixed Integer).

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer